# I'm facing problem decoding a HTML script as string value from JSON, every other value is being converted just fine

Tags: json, swift, swift3, decodable

I'm working with a JSON response where the value of a key contains HTML as string, it's not very large still it's not decoding.  Here is my JSON Response

```
{
    "authentication": {
        "3ds1": {
            "veResEnrolled": "Y"
        },
        "payerInteraction": "REQUIRED",
        "redirect": {
            "domainName": "www.abc.com"
        },
        "redirectHtml": "<div id=\"abcabcabc\" xmlns=\"xyzxyz"> <iframe id=\"redirectTo3ds1Frame\" name=\"redirectTo3ds1Frame\" height=\"100%\" width=\"100%\" > </iframe> <form id =\"xyz123\" method=\"POST\" action=\"https://domain.name" target=\"redirectTo3ds1Frame\"> <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"PaReq\" value=\"Some text" /> <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"TermUrl\" value=\"https:/url" /> <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"MD\" value=\"\" /> </form> <script id=\"authenticate-payer-script\"> var e=document.getElementById(\"someID\"); if (e) { e.submit(); if (e.parentNode !== null) { e.parentNode.removeChild(e); } } </script> </div>",
        "version": "3DS1"
    },
    "correlationId": "testxyz123450",
    "device": {
        "browser": "MOZILLA",
        "ipAddress": "127.0.0.1"
    },
    "merchant": "ABC123",
    
    "response": {
        "gatewayCode": "PENDING",
        "gatewayRecommendation": "PROCEED"
    },
    "result": "PENDING",
    "timeOfLastUpdate": "2021-07-25T06:11:09.511Z",
    "timeOfRecord": "2021-07-25T06:10:51.208Z",

}
```

This is my model by I'm using

```
// MODEL CODE

import Foundation

// MARK: - AuthPayer
class AuthPayer: Codable {
    var timeOfLastUpdate, timeOfRecord: String?
    var device: Device?
    var merchant: String?
    var authentication: Authentication?
    var result: String?
    var correlationID: String?
    var response: Response?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case timeOfLastUpdate, timeOfRecord, device, merchant, authentication, result, transaction
        case correlationID
        case response
    }

    init( timeOfLastUpdate: String?, timeOfRecord: String?,  device: Device?, merchant: String?, authentication: Authentication?, result: String?, transaction: Transaction?, correlationID: String?, response: Response?) {
        self.timeOfLastUpdate = timeOfLastUpdate
        self.timeOfRecord = timeOfRecord
        self.device = device
        self.merchant = merchant
        self.authentication = authentication
        self.result = result
        self.correlationID = correlationID
        self.response = response
    }
}

// MARK: - Authentication
class Authentication: Codable {
    var redirect: Redirect?
    var redirectHTML: String?
    var the3Ds1: The3Ds1?
    var payerInteraction, version: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case redirect
        case redirectHTML
        case the3Ds1
        case payerInteraction, version
    }

    init(redirect: Redirect?, redirectHTML: String?, the3Ds1: The3Ds1?, payerInteraction: String?, version: String?) {
        self.redirect = redirect
        self.redirectHTML = redirectHTML ?? """
            """
        self.the3Ds1 = the3Ds1
        self.payerInteraction = payerInteraction
        self.version = version
    }
}

// MARK: - Redirect
class Redirect: Codable {
    var domainName: String?

    init(domainName: String?) {
        self.domainName = domainName
    }
}

// MARK: - The3Ds1
class The3Ds1: Codable {
    var veResEnrolled: String?

    init(veResEnrolled: String?) {
        self.veResEnrolled = veResEnrolled
    }
}

// MARK: - Device
class Device: Codable {
    var browser, ipAddress: String?

    init(browser: String?, ipAddress: String?) {
        self.browser = browser
        self.ipAddress = ipAddress
    }
}

// MARK: - ValueTransfer
class ValueTransfer: Codable {
    var accountType: String?

    init(accountType: String?) {
        self.accountType = accountType
    }
}

// MARK: - Response
class Response: Codable {
    var gatewayRecommendation, gatewayCode: String?

    init(gatewayRecommendation: String?, gatewayCode: String?) {
        self.gatewayRecommendation = gatewayRecommendation
        self.gatewayCode = gatewayCode
    }
}

// MARK: - Provided
class Provided: Codable {
    var card: Card?

    init(card: Card?) {
        self.card = card
    }
}






// MARK: - Acquirer
class Acquirer: Codable {
    var merchantID: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case merchantID
    }

    init(merchantID: String?) {
        self.merchantID = merchantID
    }
}
```

by using this method I'm decoding

```
let authPayer = try? decoder.decode(AuthPayer.self, from: theJSONData)
```

from authPayer i can access **authPayer?.authentication?.redirect?.domainName**
and other all properties but **authPayer?.authentication?.redirectHTML** does not getting any value. i Have printed out the response in log and it does have all the values including "redirectHtml"

I tried Multiline String Literals to store  the value not but, I can’t figure out where it's having the issue only for "redirectHtml", i need the vqlue of redirectHtml from authPayer. Please help me out

Comment: You are ignoring an error using `try?`. Don’t do that. Remove the trailing question mark, wrap the line into an `do - catch` block and `print(error)`.

Comment: You have missed many escaping double quotes in HTML strings.

Comment: Hint: Check the spelling. Case sensitivity matters.

Comment: @vadian Thank you for the suggestion, did the decoding in a do-catch  block and printed the error, no errors were thrown

Comment: @RajaKishan I don’t really have to know what's inside "redirectHtml", I just need the value as is  :(

Comment: @vadian you sir have an eye that will embarrass eagle,  Thank you so much :)

Comment: *no errors were thrown*. This is the big disadvantage if **all** properties are declared as optional. By the way use structs instead of classes and you can delete all `Codingkeys` and `init` methods.